# Help with script over a list of files

Tags: shell-script, multimedia

I am using the following command

```
 mkvmerge -o  newfile.mkv  1.mkv  +2.mkv  +3.mkv   +4.mkv  etc...
```

this command collates the video files in the list. Usually I have this files in a folder, the number of files can change (not always 4 as in the example). I would like to get a command that:

1. take the list of mkv files in the given dir
2. run the command above.

Basically I know how to get the list, eg. FileList=$(ls *mkv)), but then I don't how to get the "+" in front of the file names escluding the first in the list.

Can somebody help with this?

Regards
Pierre

Answer (score 3):

```
LIST=''
for i in *.mkv; do
    if [ -n "$LIST" ]; then LIST="$LIST +"; fi
    LIST="$LIST$i"
done

mkvmerge -o newfile.mkv $LIST
```

Test if the list is empty; if not, you need to add a space and `+`. Then run the command with the generated list.

Comment: Instead `if..` construction you can use *bash variable expansion* `LIST=${LIST:+$LIST' +'}$i`

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
first_file=1.mkv
add_files=(!(${first_file%.mkv}).mkv)
printf "%s\n" "${first_file}" "${add_files[@]/#/+}"
1.mkv
+2.mkv
+3.mkv
+4.mkv
mkvmerge -o newfile.mkv "${first_file}" "${add_files[@]/#/+}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This method does not use a loop.
Also, to allow for embedded non-printable characters (eg. space), `ls -Q` quotes the filename

```
eval "$(ls -Q1 *.mkv | sed '1s/^/mkvmerge -o newfile.mkv /; 1!s/^/ +/' | tr -d '\n')"
```

Note that `tr` acts at the byte level, and as such will delete \x0D (newline char) embedded within non-ascii filename chars.